# Efficient method for finding 1's in binary representations

Tags: efficiency, binary

Say I have a binary number of N bits, and I need to find every combination that have M 1's. For example, if N = 3 and M = 1, then 100, 010, 001 are the allowed combinations. I have read that a more efficient way of finding these combinations for large N is by dividing the bits into two halves, and then combining combinations from each half such that the total number of 1's is M. For example, if N = 3 and M = 2, and we divide the bits into lengths of two and one, the half with one only has the combinations 0 and 1, while the half with two have the combinations 00, 01, 10, 11. 0 can only be combined with 11, and 1 can only be combined with 01 and 10. Thus the only total combinations are 011, 101, and 110.

Why is this method more effficient?

Comment: It is not, it still will enumerate on all combinations...

Comment: Strange, the problem i am working with states that this is the case

Comment: More efficient than what? Your question implies that you are comparing two methods, but I only see one here.